Flutter: Hide/Lock virtual keyboard, but TextField continues to receive characters from external keyboard
I'm trying to hide the keyboard, but have the keyboard or an external barcode reader work.
When I use the keyboardType attribute
keyboardType: TextInputType.none

the keyboard is blocked and does not work with an external keyboard

`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class QrCodeScanner extends StatelessWidget {
  QrCodeScanner({
    super.key,
  });

  final TextEditingController cBarcode = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: cBarcode,
              autofocus: true,
              showCursor: true,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              onFieldSubmitted: (String? value) {
                print('Barcode: #value');
              },
              keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
`

I tried to solve it this way:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65731765/flutter-textformfield-disable-keyboard-but-allow-accept-input
but it didn't work either

You can use TextInputFormatter class in inputFormatters property of TextField with condition.
 inputFormatters:(condition) ? [FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('.*'))]] : [],

This [FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('.*'))] TextInputFormatter doesn't allowed any characters to typed in.

Sorry, but I'm trying to hide the virtual keyboard and just use the external keyboard, I think inputFormatters doesn't help me.
Thanks for the contribution
